# How can i make the marker zoom in when it's clicked?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events

```
var neighborhoods = [{lat: 29.988097, lng: 31.442075},];
var marker = [];
var map;
function myMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
      zoom: 13,
      center: {lat: 30.024710, lng: 31.446871}
    });
}
function drop() {
    clearMarker();
    for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
      addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i * 200);  
    }
}
function addMarkerWithTimeout(position) {
    marker.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
     }))
};
function zoom(){
for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++){
    marker[i].addListener('click',function(){
        map.setZoom(15);
    })
}
}
function clearMarker() {
    for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
      marker[i].setMap(null);
    }
    marker = [];
};
```

i don't know why it's not zooming in when clicking the marker .
Or is there any other function can i use to make this happend because every thing is going well with this code except this problem

Comment: You didn't show how you construct your map. You have just shown the conponents you wrote to construct a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is not complete. So I can only guess.

I think the key problem is when to add the listener:

```
marker[i].addListener('click',function(){
    map.setZoom(15);
})
```

I guess the timing you run your `zoom()` is not right. You should add the listener when the marker is created (or before someone click on those markers).

If you add every marker with `addMarkerWithTimeout()`, I'd recommend to remove the function `zoom()`. And attach the listener in `addMarkerWithTimeout()` instead:

```
var neighborhoods = [{lat: 29.988097, lng: 31.442075},];
var marker = [];
var map;
function myMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
      zoom: 13,
      center: {lat: 30.024710, lng: 31.446871}
    });
}
function drop() {
    clearMarker();
    for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
      addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i * 200);  
    }
}
function addMarkerWithTimeout(position) {
    var singleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    singleMarker.addListener('click',function(){
        map.setZoom(15);
    })
    marker.push(singleMarker);
};
function clearMarker() {
    for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
      marker[i].setMap(null);
    }
    marker = [];
};
```